# dll not found exception in Linqpad when using Tesseract OCR software

Tags: dll, tesseract, linqpad

I am trying to use `Tesseract` OCR Software in `Linqpad`. I made the following steps:

1) I installed Tesseract 3.02 by using the installer in

https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe&

2) I added in Linqpad a reference to Tesseract through nuget, precisely the following package: a .Net wrapper for tesseract-ocr

3) I added in the PATH variable the path of Tesseract binary that contains also two native dll library

4) I installed Visual Studio x86 & x64 runtime as suggested in

https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/wiki/Error-2

However, when I try to use `tesseract` in `Linqpad` I get the following error:

> DllNotFoundException: Failed to find library "liblept168.dll" for platform x86

I suppose that the Problem is related to how use `native dll` in Linqpad.

How can I fix this Problem?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582472/linqpad-query-needs-unmanaged-deployment-item

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not enough to set 'Do not shadow assembly references' to true. I have the same exception.

Answer (score 4):

The incompatibility between LINQpad and the Tesseract nuget package is due to the way the `InteropDotNet` library loads native assemblies at run-time.

You can add the following method to your LINQpad query that has the Tesseract nuget package added, and it should allow the InteropDotNet library to find the native assemblies it needs.

```cs
static void CopyTessLibraries(string tessVersion, string platform)
    {
        var destFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory,platform);
    
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destFolder);
    
        var tessNugetFolder = new LINQPad.ObjectModel.NuGetReference("Tesseract")
                                    .GetPackageFolders()
                                    .First(folderName => folderName.Contains($@"Tesseract\{tessVersion}"));
    
        var platformFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(tessNugetFolder,platform));
        foreach (var file in platformFiles)
        {
            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
            var destFile = Path.Combine(destFolder, fileInfo.Name);
            if (!File.Exists(destFile))
            {
                fileInfo.CopyTo(destFile, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]